# Not able to post the data in Django Restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have added the experience details for the user using following models

**models.py**

```
class WorkExperienceData(BaseObjectModel):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'workexperience'
        verbose_name = 'WorkExperience Data'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="related_experience_detail", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=4000, default="")
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    reference_name_and_position = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reference_mailid = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
```

My serializers are following

**Serializers.py**

```
class WorkExperienceSerialzer(BaseModelSerializer):
    hidden_fields_to_add = {"created_by": None, "user": None}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
        super(WorkExperienceSerialzer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

    class Meta(BaseModelSerializer.Meta):
        model = WorkExperienceData
        fields = [
            "company",
            "designation",
            "description",
            "from_date",
            "to_date",
            "reference_name",
            "reference_mailid",
            "user",
            "id",
        ]
```

My views are following

**views.py**

```py
class WorkExperienceListView(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        experience = WorkExperienceData.objects.all()
        serializer = WorkExperienceSerialzer(experience, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = WorkExperienceSerialzer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    class WorkExperienceDetailsView(APIView):
        """
        Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
        """
        def get_object(self, pk):
            try:
                return WorkExperienceData.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except WorkExperienceData.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
    
        def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
            experience = self.get_object(pk)
            serializer = WorkExperienceSerialzer(experience, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
    
        def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
            experience = self.get_object(pk)
            serializer = WorkExperienceSerialzer(experience, many=True, data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
        def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
            experience = self.get_object(pk)
            experience.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

urls.py

```
path('experiecelist/', views.WorkExperienceListView.as_view()),
path('experiencedetails/<int:pk>/', 
views.WorkExperienceDetailsView.as_view()),
```

I have post request body is

```
[
    {
        "company": "something",
        "designation": "something",
        "description": "something",
        "from_date": "2020-10-15",
        "to_date": "2020-11-14",
        "reference_name": "something",
        "reference_mailid": "something@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "company": "nothing",
        "designation": "nothing",
        "description": "nothing",
        "from_date": "2020-10-25",
        "to_date": "2020-10-27",
        "reference_name": "nothing",
        "reference_mailid": "nothing@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

I wanted to do CRUD operation using the above data but I am unable to post the data as I am getting the following error

*error": [
"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
]*

I don't know where I did the mistake can someone help me please?

Comment: Could you please share the post request body that you're sending ? Or a request as a whole

Comment: @ihoryam I updated the post request body in my question.

Comment: you're sending a list of elements, however your serializer expects single element

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending a list of elements, however your serializer expects single element

You could solve this by either making separate request for each element in your list or otherwise you can try to init your serializer with many=True

```py
# in your post method of WorkExperienceListView
serializer = WorkExperienceSerialzer(data=request.data, many=True)
```

Since data is not a single object, but an array of objects